# Correct way to cast a JSON object into a typescript typed variable using a class?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

This is a more simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
export class Person{
    id:Number;
    name:String;
}

export class PersonForm{

    // This line:
    default:Person = {name: "Guy"};
    // Gives the following error:
    //  Error:(25, 5) TS2322: Type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Person'.
    //  Property 'id' is missing in type '{ name: string; }'.

    // I tried <Person>{name: "Guy"} but it gives the same error.

}
```

How can I make the compiler ignore this issue as long as Im not using non existant properties, or how do I declare the class so I can do the assignment this way instead of new Person() and then setting just the properties I want.

Note: Sending an object with all the properties into the constructor is not the solution I'm expecting. Also using an interface works because I can declare the fields optional, how can I do the same in a class?

Adding some more info:

The main goal of what I'm trying to achieve:

Find the best way to declare a class (not an interface) so I can initialize it with clean code in one line setting only the parameters I want to set. In Java you would overload constructors or use the Builder pattern.

I could certainly try the builder pattern but I'm looking for a more typescript way to do it, if there's any.

Comment: what's wrong with using an interface in this scenario? Seems like the best fit.

Comment: I think your options are to create an interface w/the optional property and have your class implement the interface or accept the interface as a constructor parameter. At the moment, there is no way to do what you want, but [others have asked](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4889) for it.

Comment: alternatively you could just make a constructor for the class and call it with a null parameter.. the interface would still be better for this case though.

Comment: @toskv  This is not the real scenario, just a simple scenario to make it easier to see the one thing I want to do. The real scenario needs a class, as I specified.

Comment: @SunilD. I already know how to do it with an interface, the question is how to do something similar with a class instead.

Comment: @SunilD. sending the interface as a parameter is the same as "Sending an object with all the properties into the constructor", with the exception that you still have to create the interface, and now you'd have both an interface and a class for the exact same object. There's a couples of correct ways to do it using an interface but I'm looking for a way without an interface in order to avoid code replication. Once again, the question is how to do it using a class.

Comment: I made an answer with a constructor. Btw, casting the incomplete object works just fine for me.

Comment: You mean my exact example works fine for you? the compiler is not throwing you that error? if not, what compiler options are you using? maybe that's what I'm looking for. The compiler configuration I'm using is the following:


{
        "compilerOptions": {
            "target": "ES5",
            "module": "system",
            "moduleResolution": "node",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
            "experimentalDecorators": true,
            "removeComments": true,
            "noImplicitAny": false
        }

Comment: As I linked to above, there's no way to do what you want at the moment. It comes right from the horses mouth in the typescript git repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the easiest way to do it, and IT IS POSSIBLE. I think I had tried it this way before but the fact that I was using the "Number" & "String" types instead of "number" & "string", might be giving me missleading errors from the compiler, the following code works wonders for me:

```
export class Person{
    constructor(
        public id?: number, // make sure you use number and string types instead of Number and String types
        public name?: string // make sure you make all properties optional using "?"
    ){}
}

export class PersonForm{
    default:Person = <Person>{name: "Guy"};
}
```

Comment: `<Person>{name: "Guy"} instanceof Person; // false`

Comment: @JohnWhite yea, {name: "Guy"}'s type is Object, if you want an instance of Person you need to call the constructor: `new Person()`

Answer (score 0):

You could write your class with a constructor.

```js
export class Person {
  constructor(public id: number, public name: string) {}
}
```

But you would have to call it like this.

```js
let person = new Person(null, "George");
```

Comment: You are setting all parameters there, I want the ability to set only the ones I want. The closest solution I have is using constructors though, so you might be on the right track.

Comment: Indeed, well you can use a factory to create the items, but as I said, <Person>{name: "Guy"} works fine for me. What version of typescript are you using?

Comment: Hey toskv I hadn't seen this comment, yea apparently the casting was fine, it was just the way to declare the class that was wrong in order to achieve what I wanted, you were on the right track but in your example you are initializing all the properties, change it so it looks like the one I posted and I'll change the accepted answer to yours.

Comment: @Langley your answer looks fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

Cast the JSON expression to `any`. The line to assign `default` becomes:

```
default: Person = <any>{ name: "Guy" };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another option to complement the other answers posted here..

If you have some object initialiser

```
{
  name:"John" 
}
```

and you explicitly want an instance of the class `Person`, but want keep the object initialiser, while keeping the defaults that the class `Person` creates, you can do it via passing the entire object into the class constructor:

```
var instance = new Person({name:"John"});
```

where

```
export class Person
{
   id:number = 0; //or generate one
   name:string = "unknown";
   constructor(opts:{id?:number; name?:string}){
      if(opts){
          this.id = opts.id || this.id;
          this.name = opts.name || this.name;
      }
   }
}
```

examples:

```
var people = [
   new Person(),
   new Person({name:"John"}),
   new Person({name:"James", id:10}),
   new Person({id:20})];
```